# Laravel - query the same column with two conditions

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I want to get all the datas that were created 30-365 days ago. Tried following codes but it's not working.

Database:

```
id     created_at

1      2022-05-09   

2      2021-06-08
```

Here id 2 was created before 365 days from today(2022-06-10), so it should not be shown. However id 1 was created before 30 days but not more than 365 days. So only id 1 should be shown.

Code 1:

```
$today = Carbon::now();
$doubtfulLoan = Loan::select('*')
->where(function($query) use ($today) {
    return $query
    ->where('created_at', '<', $today->subDays(30)->endOfDay())
    ->where('created_at', '>=', $today->subDays(365)->endOfDay());
 })
->get();
```

Output: it gives empty array

P.S if the 2nd where clause is commented, it gives both the ids and if the 1st where clause is commented, it gives id 1 only. But keeping both the condition gives empty array. What am I doing wrong?

Code 2:

```
$today = Carbon::now();
$doubtfulLoan = Loan::select('*')
   ->where([
       ['created_at', '<', $today->subDays(30)->endOfDay()], 
       ['created_at', '>=', $today->subDays(365)->endOfDay()]
   ])->get();
```

Output: it gives both the array.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get into the habit of using `CarbonImmutable` to prevent nasty surprises like this. Use this code:

```
$today = CarbonImmutable::now();
$doubtfulLoan = Loan::select('*')
->where(function($query) use ($today) {
    return $query
    ->where('created_at', '<', $today->subDays(30)->endOfDay())
    ->where('created_at', '>=', $today->subDays(365)->endOfDay());
 })
->get();
```

This is because you are doing `$today->subDays(30)->endOfDay()` which changes the instance value of the carbon instance and then doing `$today->subDays(365)->endOfDay()` which changes it again. This is however the same instance, so the query builder will do:

```
SELECT * FROM loans WHERE created_at < '395 days ago' and created_at >= '395 days ago'
```

since you have passed the same instance. This obviously is never satisfied.

Using the `CarbonImmutable` class makes all your Carbon objects immutable and any modifications will create a new instance and will not modify the existing instance.

Answer (score 1):

use laravel between method here

```
$doubtfulLoan = Loan::select('*')
 ->whereBetween('created_at',[
     today()->subDays(365)->startOfDay(),
     today()->subDays(30)->endOfDay()
 ])->get();
```